# Angular library encapsulated javascript library

Tags: javascript, angular, assets

I'm doing a buildable library with NX. The purpose to the library is to encapsulated a huge javascript library.
So, I have something like this :

```
> app
> libs
  > my-lib
    > assets
      > js
        > script1.min.js
        > script2.min.js
        > script3.min.js
      > css
      > fonts 
      > plugins
        > plugin1.min.js
        > plugin2.min.js
        > plugin3.min.js
     > src/lib/components
     > my-lib.module.ts
```

And I configured the angular.json of the app using the lib, as below :

```
architect : {
  build : {
    options : {
      asssets : [],
      scripts : [
        path_to_/script1.min.js
        path_to_/script2.min.js
        path_to_/script3.min.js
        path_to_/plugin1.min.js
        path_to_/plugin2.min.js
        path_to_/plugin3.min.js
      ]
```

It partialy works. Script 1 and 2 are well executed, but the the script 3 failed, because it try to load plugin 1, 2 and 3. I can't edit the script.

Do I need to enumerate every script that the lib will run ? Can I refer to a folder ?
How to configure my library to make scripts able to call each other, without editing the scripts ?

Comment: OR, you could add an angular service to your library, with a method that appends these scripts to the document head, and host these scripts on a cdn or webserver...

Comment: I don't have a server for host the scripts